# json success variable returns undefined , works after console.log paste

Tags: json, syntax

I have a JSON success stored in the variable data.

`console.log(data)` shows this:

```
{"day_name":"mon","h7":"h7","h8":"h8","h9":"h9"}
```

If I try and use it like this `day = data["day_name"];` it comes back as `undefined`.

When I copy the `console.log(data)` directly to the data variable

```
var data = {"day_name":"mon","h7":"h7","h8":"h8","h9":"h9"};
```

and run it again, it works fine.

I'm stuck. 
thanks for any help

Comment: What you're showing us works.  Can you provide a more complete example to demonstate the problem?

Comment: the problem is that the value stored in the data variable from success is ....{"day_name":"mon","h7":"h7","h8":"h8","h9":"h9"} which comes back as undefined yet when i copy and paste the values into var data it does work.  they are different somehow. it's got me baffled

Comment: We can appreciate that it has you baffled, but unless you can demonstrate it there isn't much we can do beyond random guesses (like the answer posted below).  So far you've essentially described that when you set the variable to `{"day_name":"mon","h7":"h7","h8":"h8","h9":"h9"}` it doesn't work, but then when you set it to `{"day_name":"mon","h7":"h7","h8":"h8","h9":"h9"}` it does work.  Clearly you're overlooking something that you're not showing us.

Comment: i went back to my original code . apart from using the variable name data i used jsonData like Ramiz put up and it worked. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your `JSON` data is still a string. Have you tried to do `JSON.parse(...)` before? Like in the example below:

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
const dayName = jsonData['day_name'];
```

Comment: i did use the json.parse but it put square brackets around the output and stopped it from working.  i may go back to it and try again .  i will use your code as it points me in the right direction. i want the key and the value separately.   thanks

Comment: *"...it put square brackets around the output..."*

@user2042410 Yes, it is an array. In that case you can access your data like that --> `jsonData[0]['dayName']`

Comment: But *should* it be an array?  While this may indeed help lead to the root of the problem, it's important for @user2042410 not to just try random things as magic wands until it "works".

Comment: @David that is true, it would be nice to see more code, since just a `JSON.parse(data)` should not put some brackets around the output if the data is really only the string representation of an object which was provided in the question.

Comment: the json came from this php file.                           echo json_encode($rows);

Comment: actually when i had the original version...... echo json_encode($rows); it added the square brackets. when i changed it to this... echo json_encode($rows[0]); it removed them